# Page numbering on the R/L corners?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, two-column, multicol, book-design

I am writing a book-style document for children stories etc. I 've found a nice border for the page background of each paper, with a special place near the corner for each page-number.

What I need now is to put the page-numbering of each page, on the bottom Left or Right side (but **near the corners** of each page) depending on even-odd logic of a book.

So far I've just managed to put with `fancyhdr` the even-odd page numbering correctly and suppress the 'Body' margins with a naive way to push the numbering at the sides. But I can't suppress the 'Body' borders, for both Odd and Even pages with the simple`\hspace` method.

I've tried `\checkoddpage` (if-then logic) and stuff but they did not work out well. The Right-Odd (RO) footer simply does not want to be pushed!!!

Any ideas pushing that remaining Odd-numbering to the side? A sample of the code follows. It's a little long sorry! (I can't include the borders-backgrounds...but I hope you can imagine-understand what is needed to be implemented here.)
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}


 %CHAPTER FORMAT
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Huge\bfseries}
{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\LARGE}
{}{1em}{}

%TABLE OF CONTENTS 
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\small}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\par\addvspace{3pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\par\addvspace{3pt}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

%PAGE NUM (RIGHT/LEFT)
\pagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-2.5cm}\LARGE{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\hspace*{1.5cm}\LARGE{\textbf{\thepage}}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footskip}{110pt}
\hoffset =0pt
}

%BEGIN DOC
\title{Pax Romana}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\chapter{Chp1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to force it, use `geometry` to alter the dimensions of the page layout. You could also look at the page style package which complements `titlesec`, but I think the key thing here is `geometry`. You ought not be changing `\footskip` as part of the page style. `geometry` won't know what is going on that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  very simple solution, loading `titleps` via the `pagestyles` option of titlesec, instead of fancyhdr:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}


 %CHAPTER FORMAT
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Huge\bfseries}
{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\LARGE}
{}{1em}{}

%TABLE OF CONTENTS
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\small}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\par\addvspace{3pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\par\addvspace{3pt}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

%PAGE NUM (RIGHT/LEFT)
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
\widenhead[2.5cm][0cm]{0cm}{1.5cm}
\sethead{}{}{}%
\setfoot[\LARGE\bfseries\thepage][][]{}{}{\LARGE\bfseries\thepage}
}
%BEGIN DOC
\title{Pax Romana}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\chapter{Chp1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Odd page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed a fine solution. Just wondering, is there also a way to adjust the `\widenhead`somehow along the way? ;increase-decrease it let's say after the 99th page?

I've tried the `\ifnum\value{page}>99`...but it does not work. Once the widenhead is set...done the `pagestyle{plain}` stays as is right?

Comment: Perhaps define another style with different values and change style at the right place, if you want to change parameters at the beginning of a chapter?